# <meta charset="utf-8"> declares encoding of own file?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I read that an HTML file has to contain the `<meta charset="utf-8">`element in the `head`-element to be standard-conforming.

Why does it make sense to specifiy the encoding of a file in the file itself? In order to read the `meta`-element one has to know the encoding already; so it seems redundant/useless to specify the encoding again.

Comment: It does of course not have to be UTF-8. And how to extract the encoding information from a file (that might be read without any additional information from f.e. HTTP headers), is specified for HTML5 here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#extracting-character-encodings-from-meta-elements

Comment: Maybe also interesting is this position in the specs, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset – f.e. it also declares, _“The element containing the character encoding declaration must be serialized completely within the first 1024 bytes of the document.”_

Comment: HTML5 documents don’t *have* to contain `meta`-`charset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until this element is read, the document is interpreted with the default encoding of the user agent. (This is often ISO-8859-1.) If the encoding is different from the default, then the document is re-interpreted according to the meta element. That's why you should place it as early as possible in the body, or preferably use an HTTP header (see below).

The hope with the `<meta>` element is that the preceding characters are all in the ASCII character set, which are interpreted correctly in just about all character sets.

In general, however, and if it is possible, this information should be sent in an HTTP response header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This ensures that the document is interpreted correctly from the start.

Comment: And default encoding means ASCII? Can you refer to the standard?

Comment: The default encoding is that of the user agent, so it's up to the client to decide that. A lot of browsers have ISO-8859-1 as their default encoding.

Comment: The entire document is interpreted according to encoding determined, so it is incorrect to say that “the rest of the document is then interpreted according to the meta element”. If a browser changes the encoding during the process, it will reprocess the document from the start.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was under the impression that the document wouldn't be entirely re-interpreted. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Why is it preferable to specify the charset in an HTTP header?  If one specify both, which will be used?

Comment: The answer given is exactly the reason it's preferable: without the HTTP header, the document could be processed as an incorrect encoding until it reaches the `<meta>` element, after which the body will be re-interpreted. HTTP header is delivered before the body so is seen earlier by the browser. The HTTP header also takes precedence over the meta element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030572/what-is-the-difference-between-the-charset-in-http-header-and-html-meta

Answer (score 2):

It's true that it's paradoxical for a document to declare its encoding within itself. And it really is only a secondary fallback. The HTTP `Content-Type` header always takes precedent if set; and it *should* always be set.

Declaring the charset in an HTML meta element makes sense in case the document is ever treated in a non-HTTP context; meaning if it's ever not served over HTTP and can hence not declare its encoding in the HTTP header. This may be the case if the document is downloaded and saved for later offline use. In this case it just so happens that most encodings are ASCII compatible, and the browser will typically try to read the document in an ASCII compatible default encoding like Latin-1 or UTF-8 (depending on the settings of the browser) until it encounters the meta tag. If your document is saved in a non-ASCII compatible encoding, say Shift-JIS or GB18030, this may or may not work depending on the default settings and how intelligently the browser can figure out what encoding it's dealing with; it's really mostly up to the browser how to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This way, you are setting metadata information about the encoding of your page. If you don't have this set, the page will be loaded with the default encoding set for the page in browser. This is extremeny inconvenient in case you have some non-ASCII characters in your page (for example shown with question marks if UTF-8 encoding is not set as the page encoding).