# Spray not detecting <meta> content-encoding

Tags: character-encoding, unmarshalling, spray

I've been having a problem with some code that is pulling the HTML string from a Spray HttpResponse and needs to work with the content type:

```
def getHtmlString(response: HttpResponse): String = {
  response.header[HttpHeaders.`Content-Type`] match {
    case Some(t) => HttpRequester.unmarshaller(response)
    case None => // more logic to detect the content-type using Tika.
  }
}
```

where the HttpRequester object declares the unmarshaller as:

```
object HttpRequester extends RequestBuilding with ResponseTransformation {
  import spray.httpx.encoding.{ Gzip, Deflate }
  val unmarshaller = decode(Gzip) ~> decode(Deflate) ~> unmarshal[String]
  ...
}
```

It works fine for most HTML I'm extracting where the `Content-Type` header declares an encoding, but on occasion (such as [this Vice page](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/scientists-want-to-mine-our-poop-for-gold)) I get a page with `Content-Type: text/html` that defines the encoding in a `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the response, within the `<head>` tag. I know [that's perfectly valid behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18801832/350029), but the resulting string I get from the unmarshaller isn't UTF-8 encoded.

It's not surprising that Spray doesn't do this offhand (it involves reading through the body, which might be more involved than Spray wants to get), and I'm assuming I'll have to write a custom `Unmarshaller[String]` to read through the body, start parsing the HTML and look if the `<head>` contains a `<meta charset="whatever">` tag, then re-encode the string that way. Just wanted to check if Spray had a facility to do that for us already.

Comment: No, spray has no such facility. Actually (and arguably), the meta tag is mostly for specifying the format on disk while the content-type charset should be used to specify how the data is encoded on the wire. If your server isn't able to provide the proper content-type you will always be left with the ambiguities of how content-type and meta-tag charset declarations (and possible conflicts) should be dealt with.